# Run unit tests after build in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, nunit

I have a C# project in Xamarin for which I've written a few NUnit unit tests. To alert me to regressions as soon as possible I'd like to have Xamarin run my unit tests after every build. I'm not using CI or a build server, everything is local to my dev machine. Is there a way to modify the build task to run my tests after each compilation?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a simple build script in which you invoke `nunit-console.exe` after your `msbuild` of your respective Xamarin projects.

Otherwise, I would personally recommend using Cake Build as it's fairly simple to get up and running and provides NUnit runners:

https://github.com/cake-build/cake (http://cakebuild.net/)

https://github.com/Redth/Cake.Xamarin (Xamarin Addin)

Both of these solutions should work fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

Taking elements from @JonDouglas' suggestion I ended up finding the  **Custom Commands** section and making an **After Build** with `nunit-console ${TargetFile}`. It's in the Options dialog here:

[image]